# According to Catholicism, does saying "God loves everyone equally" mean that God *likes* everyone equally?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, love

I have question about God's love:

When, in the Catholic Church, we say "God loves everyone equally", is it same as "God likes each of us to the same extent, and He loves us equally by His action"? or does it mean "God does *not* like each of us to the same extent, but He loves us equally by His action"?

Someone told me that God's love (or agape love) is an "act of will", which is not dependent on emotion of affection or fondness (or is different than affection or fondness); but I am having a hard time separating agape love from what we would call affection or fondness - and here is my logic:  if agape love is an "act of will", that means it is a loving action that is driven by desire.  But if we are to truly *desire* the good of someone, we must have affection or fondness towards that someone. If I force myself to conduct a good deed for someone who I dislike, I am not really *desiring* the good of the person, as my good deed is being carried out forcefully, not from the bottom of my heart. So we cannot really separate God's love from the affection or fondness that He has for us - thus "God loves everyone equally" means "God likes each of us to the same extent, and He loves us equally also by His action".

But I guess if the definition of agape as an "act of will" is to be interpreted as "loving action driven by determination" rather than "loving action driven by desire", then agape is indeed independent of emotions like affection or fondness. Going back to our previous example, if I force myself to conduct a good deed for someone whom I dislike, that means I am "determined" to do good things for him, regardless of my emotion. Is this what God's love is about? Liking some more than the others (more affection towards some of us than the others), but determined to carry out the same loving deeds to all of us? But I have always thought that God likes all of us very much to the same extent, although he does dislike our sins. It would be pretty depressing to think of the possibility that God not liking me at all, but Him carrying out all His loving actions towards me purely out of His "determination".

So again, I am back to my question: According to Catholicism, when we say "God loves everyone equally", is it same as "God likes each of us to the same extent, and He loves us equally by His action"? or does it mean "God does not like each of us to the same extent, but He loves us equally by His action"?

PS: Some may object that God does not have affection or fondness because he is impassible; but there is also a view that God is impassible but also impassioned. However, that is a whole different discussion.

Comment: Related: [Biblical basis for God's egalitarian love](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/39395)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biblical basis for God's egalitarian love](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39395/biblical-basis-for-gods-egalitarian-love)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate of the linked question, since it appears to be asking for the Roman Catholic understanding.

Comment: Hello, I took a look at the previous post that you mentioned, but I don't see it being equivalent to what I am asking because none of the answers seem to depict that "God likes everyone equally". They all assert that "God loves everyone equally", but what I am asking here is essentially whether "God loves everyone equally" means "God likes everyone equally"

Comment: It is related to a question that I just answered: [Will we still feel affection towards others when we are in heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45677/will-we-still-feel-affection-towards-others-when-we-are-in-heaven) Although that question answered whether _humans_ feel affection in Heaven (they do), it also touched on whether God has “feelings” in the strict sense (which He does not). Everything that for us is divided into “liking” and “loving”, in God is a single, infinitely intense act of love.

Comment: I should specify: God _in His Divine Nature_ is above feelings of any kind. Naturally, Jesus in his _human_ nature did (and still does) have feelings.

Comment: It all boils down to how the Catholic Church defines "love".  For me, love is "an affection or fondness that is strong enough to prompt one to desire the good of someone or something". Do you agree with this definition? Some say that love is "will", not "emotion" like fondness, but I don't think it is right to separate the two, since emotions like fondness can have an effect on our desire - if we really like someone, our desire for the good of that person is stronger than our desire for the good of some stranger. After all, is love really a love if it is not accompanied by genuine affection?

Comment: @MattGutting: You explain the Angelic Doctor better: [Home > Summa Theologica > First Part > Question 20. God's love](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/1020.htm)

Comment: @FMS Search Twitter for (no quotes) "#SummaHaiku Q20".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St. Thomas Aquinas answers this question in his [*Summa Theologica* I q. 20 a. 3 ("Whether God loves all things equally?")](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP020.html#FPQ20A3THEP1) c., making a twofold distinction:

> Since to love a thing is to will it good, in a twofold way anything may be loved more, or less.
>
> 1. In one way **on the part of the act of the will itself**, which is more or less intense. In this way **God does not love some things more than others**, because He loves all things by an act of the will that is one, simple, and always the same.
> 2. In another way **on the part of the good itself** that a person wills for the beloved. In this way we are said to love that one more than another, for whom we will a greater good, though our will is not more intense. In this way we must needs say that **God loves some things more than others**. For since God's love is the cause of goodness in things, as has been said ([Article [2]](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP020.html#FPQ20A2THEP1)), no one thing would be better than another, if God did not will greater good for one than for another.

Comment: In other words God does not love everyone equally.  He wishes a greater good for some than for others.  The idea that God loves all equally is not a Catholic dogma so much as a democratic egalitarian dogma!

Comment: @zippy2006 God loves some more than others because he gives some greater gifts/goods than others, but He loves all equally because His Son redeemed all of humanity equally.

Comment: Do you have any source for your idea that he loves all equally?  I don't think you will find Catholic sources inferring a kind of egalitarian love from the redemption.  In any case, the graces by which we are redeemed are not equal, and our place in heaven will not be equal.  Christ atones for the sins of all, but this does not mean God loves everyone equally.

Comment: @zippy2006 I simply summarized what I quoted in my answer: "In one way on the part of the act of the will itself, which is more or less intense. In this way God does not love some things more than others, because He loves all things by an act of the will that is one, simple, and always the same."

Comment: But that says nothing at all about your claim, "...because His Son redeemed all of humanity equally."  St. Thomas says that the intensity of God's will does not change with respect to different people, but the good that he wills them differs.  So God wills more or less good to certain people while maintaining the same intensity of will.  For example, why did God give Mary more grace?  Because he loved her more, says St. Thomas.

Comment: @zippy2006 So God did not redeem all equally?

Comment: I never said that.  You said, "God loves all equally because His Son redeemed all of humanity equally."  That is false.  God does not love all equally, and nowhere in Catholic teaching will you find the idea that the redemption implies equality of love.

Comment: @zippy2006 It seems you don't understand love in sense #1, and you're adamant in asserting I only use love in sense #2. How do you understand the distinction St. Thomas is making between these two senses of love?

Comment: St. Thomas says that to love a thing is to will it good.  He then says that we can look at love from the aspect of the will or the aspect of the good.  Since there is but one act of God's will, no difference in love comes from the part of the will.  Since there are many different goods willed, a difference does come on the part of the good.  Now if love is constituted of two parts and from one part comes an equality of love and from the other an inequality, then the sum total is an inequality of love.

Comment: It's interesting to note that our exchange very much parallels objection 2 where Aquinas says that although the intensity of the love on the part of the will is the same for all, this does not mean that the good God wills for creatures does not vary in degree.

Comment: @Geremia St. Thomas is not at all making a distinction between two senses of love. You've completely misunderstood the passage. One car could be faster than another because it has a more powerful engine, or because it is lighter. That doesn't mean there is a distinction between "different senses of faster", or that a Nissan Versa is "faster" than a Ferrari "in the sense that it is lighter".